# Unable to load CSV as viewable features

Tags: qgis, point, csv

Have tried loading a *.CSV* using Delimited Text tool. When it Loads up, it only loads as an attribute table with no spatial view.

What am I doing wrong?

[image]
[image]

Comment: I think your problem is that your lat/lon fields are not numeric - they are treated as strings because of the presence of the degree symbol and the S and E direction indications. I would suggest extracting the first couple of lines from your file and using a text editor to make the values purely numeric (making the south latitudes negative), then importing the layer as you did. If this fixes the problem, you have to figure out how to edit the full file. You might get away with search/replace in a text editor I would think.

Comment: If you know how to write functions in a spreadsheet, you could open the CSV in that, and extract the numbers from the coordinates that way.